# Symfony : redirect after submit in Twig render() method

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I have a few posts in Twig view. For each post, I want to add a form comment.

For best reusable, I call `render(controller())` in Twig.

`Twig` :

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\User\\PostController::comment',
    {
        'post': post,
    }
)) }}
```

`Controller` :

```
public function comment(Request $request, Post $post): Response
{
    $comment = new PostComment();
    $comment->setPost($post);

    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('post_comment_' . $post->getId(), PostCommentType::class, $comment)->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest());

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($comment);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->redirectToRoute(...); // ERROR
    }

    return $this->render('user/post/_comment.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

But I can't redirect after submit. I understand that it's complicated from a view, HttpRequest has already passed.

This is error :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Error when rendering "http://project.local/index.php/u/root/post" (Status code is 302).").

Do you have a solution for me ? Thanks you :)

Comment: I want to be sure: When you submit your form from your rendered controller, you want to be redirected ?

Comment: Yes :) I want to redirect after each valid submission :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is handling your invalid form.

**1) redirection during submission**

If you don't care your user is on the comment page (not the render) if his form is invalid, you can simply add in your rendered template:

```
{# 'user/post/_comment.html.twig' #}
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('your_comment_route')}) }}
```

or

**2) Redirecting using javascript after submission**

If you want the user to stay in the same page if the form has error, I don't see any other solution than adding a parameter to change the result of your controller

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\User\\PostController::comment', {
        'post': post,
        'embedded': true,
 } )) }}
```

Then in your controller

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        if($embedded) {
           return $this->render('user/post/success.html.twig', [
              //call this route by javascript?
              'redirectRoute': $this->generateUrl()//call it in twig, it's just for better understanding
           ])
        } else {
            $this->redirectToRoute(...); 
        }
    }
```